# php file treated in the fundamental mode

Tags: php-mode

I work in Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu

The php file is treated in the fundamental mode:

[image]

How to fix?

**Trying installation of the *phps-mode* package**

I installed the package phps-mode (https://github.com/cjohansson/emacs-phps-mode) with ELPA. `M-x package-list-package` lists this package:

[image]

`~/.emacs.d/elpa/phps-mode-0.4.30` is in the `load-path`.

The php files are still treated in the Fundamental mode.

After the installation there is no PHP entry in `auto-mode-alist`. Adding the line

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . phps-mode))
```

(or ... `php-mode` - which one to use?)

to the file `~/emacs.d/init.el` produces an error:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function phps-mode)
```

[image]

After adding `(require 'phps-mode)` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` there is an error:

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, phps-mode
```

The php files are still treated in the Fundamental mode.

Comment: May depend on installed package; see this for example: https://github.com/cjohansson/emacs-phps-mode

Comment: Check the value of `auto-mode-alist` and see if there is a PHP entry in it. If not, you can add one by hand: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))` - add that to your init file. However, if you are loading a package to get a `php-mode`, the package initialization should take care of those details, so you might want to investigate why it's not happening.

Comment: @NickD, how to check the value `auto-mode-alist`?

Comment: It's a variable, so you check it with `C-h v auto-mode-alist` - but it's a variable with a loooong value, so switch to the `*Help*` buffer and use `C-s php` to search for an entry.

Comment: @NickD PHP was not in the `auto-mode-alist` adding `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))` to the init file didn't bring about any effect

Comment: @Ian I installed from ELPA the package in https://github.com/cjohansson/emacs-phps-mode, however the php files are still treated in the fundamental mode

Comment: @NickD and did you mean `php-mode` or `phps-mode`?

Comment: In the provided link, the last paragraph, second line is an example how to do -seems a little bit different of what you have done - try to correct it (if you use ```require```, if you use ```use-package```, there are some other examples there).

Comment: @Ian when using `(require 'phps-mode)` there is an error: `File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, phps-mode`

Comment: I don't know what modes are available for PHP editing, so just use whichever one you  want to use and have available.

Comment: Do you have in your ```init.el```, at the beginning, a line like this: ```(add-to-list 'load-path (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa"))```?

Comment: @Ian, I added. No change.

Comment: Rename your ```init.el``` file to something else and create a new ```init.el``` file with the content only the last paragraph in GitHub ```emacs-php-mode``` and restart emacs. See if works.